# MySQL workbench doesn't work with a certain script that works on other computers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a (not so)slight problem. I have this SQL file which works perfectly in all computers, but mine. And since it doesn't work in mine, coding in my end is kind of difficult. It gives me this 1822 error with no real explanation since I can't replicate it on other systems. Any clue on what could be happening?

```
use marioTallerizo;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS concesionarios (
    id_concesionario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50),
    telefono VARCHAR(15),
    codigo_postal INT(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_concesionario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (
    id_concesionario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_usuario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    usuario VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    contrasena VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(50),
    direccion VARCHAR(50),
    telefono VARCHAR(15),
    codigo_postal INT(5),
    rol VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario , dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_concesionario)
        REFERENCES concesionarios (id_concesionario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jefe (
    id_usuario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario)
        REFERENCES usuarios (id_usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vehiculos (
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_concesionario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    numero_bastidor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    especialidad ENUM('coche', 'motocicleta', 'ciclomotor'),
    precio INT(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_vehiculo , numero_bastidor),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_concesionario)
        REFERENCES concesionarios (id_concesionario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes (
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_cliente INT(9) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(50),
    direccion VARCHAR(50),
    telefono VARCHAR(15),
    codigo_postal INT(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo)
);

create table if not exists ventas (
    id_usuario int(9) NOT NULL,
    id_venta int(9) NOT NULL,
    id_cliente int(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_venta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)
);   
    
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mecanicos (
    id_usuario INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    especialidad ENUM('Coche', 'Moto', 'Camion'),
    es_jefe BIT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario)
        REFERENCES usuarios (id_usuario),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coches (
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    precio INT(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_vehiculo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo)
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS motocicletas (
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    precio INT(6),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo)
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ciclomotor (
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    precio INT(6),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo)
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reparaciones (
    id_reparacion INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_vehiculo INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_mecanico INT(9) NOT NULL,
    fecha_entrada DATE,
    fecha_salida DATE,
    presupuesto INT,
    piezas ENUM('tornillos', 'tuercas'),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_reparacion),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo)
        REFERENCES vehiculos (id_vehiculo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_mecanico)
        REFERENCES mecanicos (id_usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS propuestas (
    id_propuesta INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_ventas INT(9) NOT NULL,
    id_cliente INT(9) NOT NULL,
    precio INT(50),
    vendido BIT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_propuesta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ventas)
        REFERENCES ventas (id_venta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente)
        REFERENCES clientes (id_cliente)
);


insert into concesionarios values (1, 'Peugeot', 'Avenida VelÃ¡zquez', '952759027', '29005');

insert into usuarios values (1, 1, '74637189H' , 'carlosfm', 'hola', 'Carlos', 'FernÃ¡ndez', 'Calle MÃ¡rmoles', '684727185', '29002', 'Mecánico');
insert into usuarios values (1, 1, '74637189T' , 'proxo', 'hola', 'Carlos', 'FernÃ¡ndez', 'Calle MÃ¡rmoles', '684727185', '29002', 'Ventas');
insert into jefe values (1);

insert into vehiculos values (1, 1, 'VSSZZZ1MZ2R040807', 'coche', '20000');
insert into vehiculos values (2, 1,'VSSZZZ1MZ2R040807', 'motocicleta', '20000');
insert into vehiculos values (3, 1, 'VSSZZZ1MZ2R040807', 'ciclomotor', '20000');

-- PROBLEMA. NO PUEDE HABER UN CLIENTE CON EL MISMO DNI QUE UN JEFE O UN MECÃ�NICO
insert into clientes values (1, 1, '74829187B', 'Manuel', 'Jurado', 'Calle Mármoles', '638192847', '29001');

insert into ventas values (1, 1, 1);

insert into mecanicos values (1, 1, 'Coche', 0);

insert into coches values (1, '15000');

-- PROBLEMA. SE PUEDE INSERTAR UN MISMO NUMERO DE BASTIDOR EN LA TABLA COCHE, MOTOCICLETA Y CICLOMOTOR Y NO DEBERÃ�A

insert into motocicletas values (2, '2000');

insert into ciclomotor values (3, '1000');

insert into reparaciones values (1, 2, 1, '2020-10-20', '2020-10-28', '200', 'tornillos');

insert into propuestas values (1, 1, 1, '23000', 0);
```

The error says:
`Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'propuestas_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'ventas'`

It should be creating the table with no problems, but can't create the "propuestas" table because of that error.

Comment: Check the ventas table after creation, something may have gone wrong there with the primary key.

Comment: I have run your script in my local mysql workbench and it has finished without any problem, maybe it is necessary to delete some indexes: [MySQL Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html#:~:text=To%20add%20an%20index%2C%20click,in%20the%20Index%20Columns%20list.).